# import csv data to mongodb node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

im try to export data from csv file to mongodb collection at once using streams of node js and csv-parser lib

```
const fs = require("fs");
const csv = require("csv-parser");
const mongodb = require("mongodb");
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/testbd";
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

const readStream = fs.createReadStream("./bigCsv.csv", "utf8");
const csvData = csv()
  .on("data", (data) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      client
        .db("testbd")
        .collection("test_collection")
        .insertMany([data], (err, res) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(res);
        });
    });
  })
  .on("end", () => {
    console.log("insert done");
  });

readStream.pipe(csvData);
```

here is how im tryed to do no errors on "end" emmiter is working but in data nothing is added have someone idea to handle this issue?

Comment: You can also subscribe to 'error' event and check for any errors there

Comment: i know but i have no errors becouse this i canot search solution